# Beating CSRF using Tokens

Tags: web-application

I am new to web programming. I read an article where they advised to use tokens as a hidden field in forms and match that token at the server end to detect non-legitimate requests. I am wondering what difference does it make, if an attacker uses an iframe to fetch a form,that form is going to have the token id generated at server and it should be matched.I went through article on owasp.org but it sounds too cryptic for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the attacker embeds your form on his site, we're talking about a very different attack called [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking). A token doesn't help against clickjacking, you need different methods of protection (specifically the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header or JavaScript framebusters).

Cross-site request forgery means that the attacker creates his *own* form pointing to your site. Then the attacker tricks the victim (or the victim's browser) into submitting the form and taking actions on his behalf.

A token does help against CSRF, because the attacker doesn't know the token of the victim and hence cannot prepare a valid request. However, there are some limitations. If you use cookie-based protection, then an attacker might be able to set his own cookie with a known token. And cross-site scripting vulnerabilities generally break all CSRF protection.

Comment: It means if  I use a hidden Iframe to auto submit the form and the user is logged in,tokens are not going to prevent that anyway.Also how cookie-based protection makes it vulnerable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “use a hidden iframe to auto-submit the form”. If *you* create the form, then you need to know the victim's token in order to prepare a valid request. Since you don't know the token, you can't. If you embed the target page in a frame and use *their* form, then this a clickjacking attack, not CSRF. A token doesn't help against clickjacking, but nobody made that claim in the first place.

Comment: with a little more effort the attacker's website can obtain the user's token with a simple request, read out the token, and reuse it when sending the malicious request. am i missing something? maybe it wouldn't work due to a browser's cross domain policy?

Comment: If a website could simply read the content of other websites through the user's browser, we'd have much bigger problems. Imagine arbitrary site owners visiting your PayPal account, reading your e-mails with your webmailer, buying things with your Amazon account etc. So, no, this is *not* possible. And it's indeed the same-origin policy which prohibits it.

Comment: @PhilippMurry: The item you're looking for is the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - this prevents cross domain reads, amongst other things.